# Flutter: How to add a header to websockets sink.add

Tags: flutter, websocket

Hello everyone I use the websocket_channel library for flutter, when I connect I get a live_id, the id is needed for further messages that I will send to the server, I connect to the database in this way:

`channel = New IOWebSocketChannel.connection('ws://host.com/',headers: headers);`

Let's say that to disconnect I need to send a json body

`{
  type: 2,
  id: 1
}`

and I also need to pass the live_id in the header, how can I do this?